# search for a specific term then output data in same row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Hello i am trying to write a formula in excel to generate a report. I have 4 columns C D E F . What i want to do is check column F for a specific term "Fair - DPS Actionable". If this text appears exactly, then I need to have the text in the same row but column C displayed on a new tab. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` only works **from left to right** and search index is first column in range.
What you are looking for is **right to left indexing** and that could be done with `INDEX(MATCH())`.
Here is an example:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Fair - DPS Actionable",F:F,0))
```

In your case you will most likely need to reference another sheet so `C:C` will be something like `Sheet1!C:C` and `F:F` will be `Sheet1!F:F`. Also, `0` at the end of this formula indicates that you are looking for exact match. Lastly, you can change the text in this formula into a cell reference for easier manipulation. Hope this solves it for you.

Comment: this works thanks -- I would like for the formula to check a range of tabs and then output ALL of the findings in one column, is that possible?